# Formulation VS Interpretation

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, philosophy

I'm reading a book on Mathematical Physics and at some point the author says that we must distinguish between a "formulation" and an "interpretation" of a theory, although it's not easy to point what is pure "formulation" and pure "interpretation" sometimes. That thought had never occurred to me.

I think what the author suggests is more profound than thinking of a variable "t" as being "time" in an equation. Can  anyone make it clearer to me what the author is trying to say ?
Some examples maybe...

In other words: What  do you understand by "formulation" and "interpretation" ? Do you think of it as different things ?

PS: My question may be a little bit vague but that is as clear as I could make it, don't know which tags are appropriate, thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be better suited to http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that it is fairly clear what *interpretation* means in the context of a mathematical theory (or a physical theory using mathematics) : see [Model Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/) and [Models in Science](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/models-science/), but it is not clear what the author of your "book on Mathematical Physics" means with *formulation*.

What does it mean *fomulation* ?

With this word the author means simply the "exposition" of the theory ? see e.g. [The Scientific Worldview](http://thescientificworldview.blogspot.it/2009/05/theory-formulation.html) :

> The question has been asked: In what way is theory formulated?
>
> 1. Theory formulation begins with fundamental presuppositions (unconscious) or assumptions (conscious).

or he is alluding to the more "technical" meaning of [formalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) ?

Comment: I do not think that *interpretation* in mathematical physics means Model Theory, because mathematical physicists generally avoid “formal system vs domain” discourse. My guess: “formulation” is a PDE and an appropriate function space, whereas “interpretation” is a set of solvable problems, such as Cauchy problem.